# What’s wrong with my cacti

Tags: plant-care, cactus

My cacti look very ill, and I don’t understand what I am doing wrong and what’s going on. Could someone please help me with advice of what to do?

[image][image]

Comment: I have to flex my head to the left to see the images properly... When I do that, I see the picture on the left (with the three stems), which has probably signs of sunburn. Maybe wait and hope that new healthy growth will form, and in time try to propagate the healthy parts by cuttings.

Comment: Sorry for the upload, I’ve never used this website before and did it via phone.. thank you for the advice!